# constrained zero-sum two person game

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, saddlepoint

Finding the saddle point of a constrained zero-sum two-person game is equivalent to a resolution of primal-dual programs (with bi-linear objective function).

I am looking for a free solver to compute the saddle point in the constrained zero-sum two-person game (in primal-dual programs with linear constraints and bilinear objective function).

Primal-dual programs
$$
\begin{align}
\max_x \qquad &x^tAy \\
\text{s.t.} \qquad & Bx \leq b \\
& x_i\geq 0 \\
& x_1+x_2 +\dots+x_m = 1, \\ \\
\min_y \qquad &x^tAy \\
\text{s.t.} \qquad & Dy \leq d \\
& y_i\geq 0 \\
& y_1+y_2 +\dots+y_n = 1.
\end{align}
$$